# Unable to get the response in jquery after sending email from codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, email

I am not getting the response after including the send email function to the controller but code sends email perfectly only issue is not getting response. If I remove the code that sends email then in that case response is fine from the controller but when I include the email function I am not getting the response on jquery view code.

I am posting my controller code with the email function code also post my jQuery so that you can review it.

**Controller code:**
    **/*******Create new customer*******/**

```
public function createcustomer()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname", "First Name", "required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("lastname", "Last Name", "required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email", "required|is_unique[gab_users.email]|trim|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]|matches[confirmpassword]|md5');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|min_length[5]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        die("fail");
    }
    else
    {
        $activation_code = sha1(uniqid($this->input->post('email'),'true'));
        $data = array("firstname"=>$this->input->post('firstname'), "lastname"=>$this->input->post('lastname'), "email"=>$this->input->post('email'), "password"=>$this->input->post('password'), "ip"=>$this->input->post('ip'), "activation_code"=>$activation_code, "created_on"=>now(), "active"=>1, "group"=>2);
        $verifyCreate = $this->index_model->set_user($data);

        if($verifyCreate === "success")
        {               

                if($this->sendEmail() === 'done')//If I remove this line and write only die('done'); its work perfectly. model is working fine data is saved in the database in both conditions. The big issue is response?
                {die('done');}
        }
        else
        {
            die("invalid");
        }

    }

}
**/******Send Email********/**
public function sendEmail()
{
      $this->load->library('email'); 
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('email@gmail.com', 'Name');
      $this->email->to('*****@gmail.com');
      $this->email->subject(' My mail through codeigniter from localhost '); 
      $this->email->message('Hello World…');
      if (!$this->email->send()) {
        die(show_error($this->email->print_debugger())); 
        }
      else {
        die("done"); //I have also check it by return same thing is happened
      }
}
```

**My Jquery code written in view side:**

```
<script>$().ready(function() {
    $("#regForm").validate({
        rules: 
        {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            email: 
            {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: 
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirmpassword: 
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        messages: 
        {
            firstname: "First Name Required",
            lastname: "Last Name required",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            password: 
            {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            confirmpassword: 
            {
                required: "Please provide a password confirmation",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) 
        {alert('customer register');
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>createcustomer",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
                if(data == 'done')
                {
                    $.blockUI({ css: {
                                border: 'none',
                                padding: '15px',
                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                                opacity: .5,
                                color: '#fff'
                            } });

                            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
                    $('#successreg').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>customer";
                    }, 7000);

                }
                else if(data == 'invalid')
                {
                   $.blockUI({ css: {
                                border: 'none',
                                padding: '15px',
                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                                opacity: .5,
                                color: '#fff'
                            } });

                            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
                            $('#regerrormsg').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>customer";
                    }, 7000);
                }
                else
                {
                   $.blockUI({ css: {
                                border: 'none',
                                padding: '15px',
                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                                opacity: .5,
                                color: '#fff'
                            } });

                            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
                    $('#regerrormsg').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>customer";
                    }, 7000);
                }
            }
          });
          return false;
        }

    });

}); </script>
```

Please advise why I am not getting response from the controller after using the sendEmail function while the email is send and data is saved to the database but not getting response so I am unable to display the confirmation message to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Note the below all that is good stuff as well but your actual issue is how you are returning from your `sendMail()` function. `Die` is wrong as it will kill the script dead (clue is in the name) so it wont progress to allow the calling script to respond. Change to:

```
 ....
 if (!$this->email->send()) {
    die(show_error($this->email->print_debugger())); 
    }
  else {
    return "done"; 
  }
```

Die is not good practice for a http response as it might be construed as a broken page. Why not return something the jQuery likes eg a json string. For example:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if($verifyCreate === "success")
    {               

            if($this->sendEmail() === 'done'){
                 echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'));
                 return;
            }
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'fail'));
        return;
    }
```

Then in your jQuery

```
    //redacted
    success: function(data) {
         if(data.status==='success'){
              //do some success stuff
         }
         else if(data.status==='fail'){
              //do some fail stuff
         }else{
              //do some unexpected stuff
         }
    }
```

You might also need to set `contentType:json` in your $.ajax object.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am still getting the same nothing happen. I am confused about the jquery part. In jquery I am posting data by using the $(form).serialize() form data and when I add the contentType: "application/json" to the ajax nothing happen.

Can you post the correct jquery part of my code so that I can get correct response. It will be a great help

Comment: ahhh...finally got response. I have increase the timeout period in ajax script and now got correct response.

Thanks for the great help. I will accept your response as answer thanks

Comment: The content type header needs to be in php so the jquery knows its getting json back and automagically converts the response into a js object

Comment: I haven't do that it's working only by increasing the timeout period